# Calculating Solar hourly irradiance

Tags: radiation

Assuming direct normal solar irradiance is ***I***, then $\ I * cos( \theta$) gives the irradiance on a tilted surface in W/m2. Integrating this over a period of time:

[image]       (J/m2)

and the same integral over ***dω*** (angle) is in Wh/m2.

***Edit:***

Although the unit is in Wh/m2 (Watt *Hour* per sq meter) but the integration is on dω(angles). This is where I am getting confused. Should it not be on dt instead?

And to get the average hourly irradiance, is it correct to divide the the above integrand(over a period of a day) by 24(or $\ 2 \pi$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radiant exposure $H$ can be found from  $H = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} I \mbox{ d}t$

or the average solar irradiance could be found from $\langle I \rangle = \frac{1}{t_2-t_1} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} I \mbox{ d}t$

so you would divide by 24 hours, assuming you were including the night in your hourly average

Comment: maybe you can edit the question? I couldn't really understand what's being asked

Comment: sorry I perhaps couldn't explain it properly. I have edited the question. Hope it's more clear.